# Injecting mocks and using constructor instantiation

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I'm trying to write TestNG test cases for my `Class A`. `Class A` does a static initialization of `Class B`. `Class A` also has a *single arg constructor* and takes in `C` which is an `enum`. When I try to run my test cases, Mockito does not mock `B` inside `A` even though I have called `@InjectMocks` over `A`.

**Class A:**

```
public class A{

    private static B b = new B();

    public A(C c){
    ....
    }
    .....
}
```

**Test Class:**

```
public class ATest {

@InjectMocks
private A a= new A(C.valueOf("somevalue"));

@Mock
private B B;

@BeforeClass
public void setUp() throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void testSomething() {
..... // still uses B. (Found using coverage tool)
}
```

**Note:** I actually have a factory method to create `A`. But in order to test `A`, I need to create a test class and hence I've initialized `A` directly using the enum here.

Please tell me how to achieve testing in this case.

**Edit:** Just tried to use `Whitebox` to set the internal state of `b` to my mocked `b`. But my class still uses the real `b` and not the mocked object.

Comment: Just at a glance, could it be that you need to define your mock before you InjectMocks?

Comment: Tried that as well. Still my class A uses B instead of the mock.

Comment: Having another look it seems 'b' is instanciated in class 'A' rather than injected. It's been a while since I've done mocking in Java but I think your 'A' class should just define that is has an object of type B and not define a `new B()`; You may also need to add a parameter for 'b' to the constructor of 'A'.

Comment: @JamesWebb yes, I actually wanted to `@Inject` `b` inside `A`. But when I do that, Spring doesn't start the application since it needs the constructor value. In my application, the constructor is populated and passed only at runtime. Hence the usage of static initialization.

Comment: Doesn't that then become the responsibility of the factory method? Apologies I'm beginning to get out of my depth here as I have very limited experience with Java.

I hope my basic questions have atleast helped a little.